# Making sure a web page is not cached, across all browsers

Tags: caching

You said you put these lines, but where and how do I put this in my html?

I used those below, but they didn't work in all browsers

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

Comment: In which browsers did you find they did not work?  How did you confirm that they didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Put them anywhere between `<head>` and `</head>`, but after the tag `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" ...>` if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

[`meta`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#edef-META) goes into the `<head>` of the document.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
</head>
<body>
  <p>hi!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

They go in between <head> and </head>.